# find inside shell function

Tags: bash, alias, function, arguments

I try to put `find` inside function and catch an argument passed to this function with the following minimal work example:

```
function DO
{
    ls $(find . -type f -name "$@" -exec grep -IHl "TODO" {} \;)
}
```

But, when I execute `DO *.tex`, I get “find: paths must precede expression:”. But when I do directly:

```
ls $(find . -type f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -IHl "TODO" {} \;)
```

then I get all TeX files witch contain "TODO".

I try many thing in the `DO` function, such as `\"$@\"`, `'$@'`, I change the quotes marks, but the behavior still the same.

So, what to do to force find work inside function?

Comment: If you have two files ending in .tex, your command would be expanded by the calling shell to, say, `DO f1.tex f2.tex`, and the _find_ command would see `... -name f1.tx f2.tex ...`, which is invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

1. The `*.tex` pattern will be expanded when calling the function `DO`, if it matches any filenames in the current directory.  You will have to quote the pattern as either `'*.tex'`, `"*.tex"` or `\*.tex` when calling the function.
2. The `ls` is not needed.  You already have both `find` and `grep` that are able to report the pathnames of the found files.
3. `-name "$@"` only works properly if `"$@"` contains a single item.  It would be better to use `-name "$1"`.   For a solution that allows for multiple patterns, see below.

The function may be written

```
DO () {
   # Allow for multiple patterns to be passed,
   # construct the appropriate find expression from all passed patterns

   for pattern do
       set -- "$@" '-o' '-name' "$pattern"
       shift
   done

   # There's now a -o too many at the start of "$@", remove it
   shift

   find . -type f '(' "$@" ')' -exec grep -qF 'TODO' {} ';' -print
}
```

Calling this function like

```
DO '*.tex' '*.txt' '*.c'
```

will make it execute

```
find . -type f '(' -name '*.tex' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.c' ')' -exec grep -qF TODO {} ';' -print
```

This would generate a list of pathnames of files with those filename suffixes, if the files contained the string `TODO`.

To use `grep` rather than `find` to print the found pathnames, change the `-exec ... -print` bit to `-exec grep -lF 'TODO' {} +`.  This will be more efficient, especially if you have a large number of filenames matching the given expression(s). In either case, you definitely do not need to use `ls`.

---

To allow the user to use

```
DO tex txt c
```

your function could be changed into

```
DO () {
   # Allow for multiple patterns to be passed,
   # construct the appropriate find expression from all passed patterns

   for suffix do
       set -- "$@" '-o' '-name' "*.$suffix"   # only this line (and the previous) changed
       shift
   done

   # There's now a -o too many at the start of "$@", remove it
   shift

   find . -type f '(' "$@" ')' -exec grep -qF 'TODO' {} ';' -print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the parameter to the function, otherwise shell expands it and the function gets a list of files, not a wildcard mask:

```
DO "*.tex"
```

You can then use just `"$1"` instead of `"$@"`, as there will only be one parameter.

Comment: This solution work but it break the expected usage of commands :/

Comment: So the expectation was wrong. There's a reason you need to quote the mask for find.

Comment: What about `"$*"` instead of `"$@"`? Might work if the filenames don't contain spaces.

Comment: No, `$*` expands all the arguments but as a single string. The only way to get `*.tex` into the `find -name` parameter from the command line is to quote it.

Comment: @fauve if you're looking for files that end with `.tex` could you change your  tool to expect just `tex` on the command line? You could then do something like `find ... -name "*.$1"`